# Problem in upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

While updating Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10, it is giving an error:

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker1_9.0.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Please help.

Also, my machine is not getting completely shutdown while shutting the machine off.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the main repositories while upgrading. To do that open a `terminal`, type:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and on the first tab choose `Main repository`, enter your password when promted, than close and run:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

If does not work, you can first remove `libxatracker1`, and try like that. If you use `vmware`, you can reinstall it after the upgrade.

Comment: how to remove libxatracker1 or vmware???

Comment: With: `sudo apt-get purge libxatracker1`